# Invoke block immediately after definition

Tags: ios, block

I have some code like this:

```
void (^testBlock)() = ^ {
    NSLog(@"TEST");
};
testBlock();
```

Can I invoke the block immediately after definition like:

```
void (^testBlock)() = ^ {
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}();
```

This's a good way when the block is just invoked once. Any ideas?

Comment: Run Xcode project and see it work or not.

Comment: I tried your code in XCode and it shows a compilation error. you want to invoke the block only then there is another called dispatch_once. is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @CRDave Of course not, 。

Comment: @NitheeshGeorge My concern is __Invoke block immediately after definition__. Like `(function() {})()` in JavaScript.

Comment: I thought compile error will make u solve this. But any way write this code ^()
    {
        NSLog(@"TEST");
    }();

Comment: For more detail on block read this : http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/

Comment: If you want the block to be invoked just once and If you want to invoke it immediately, then why bother using a block at all?

Comment: @GoGreen Make code clean and easy for read. Doing specific thing in the block.

Comment: What I suggest is to keep all block definitions in a separate method say "loadBlocks" and call it initially from `viewDidLoad`. Defining a block and using it immediately doesn't help in code clean up or readability to me. Simple commenting would do the thing.

Comment: @GoGreen How to refer blocks after `loadBlocks `?

Comment: Declare a block of the same type as a property, and then set this property with the corresponding block in `loadBlocks`. This keeps a reference to it, which you may invoke at anytime. Using typedefs to create a block type will further help in readability.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `void (^testBlock)() = ^ {...}();` you actually try to keep a reference to whatever the block returns, not the block itself.
Xcode throws:

```
Initializing 'void(^__strong)()' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'.
```

In other words - your block returns nothing (void), and you are trying to hold it with strong reference of type `void(^)()`, which is your block type.

Assuming you want a reference to the block, you must first declare the block, and than call it through the name you gave the reference to it, like you showed in your first snippet.

If on the other hand, you wish to declare a block and invoke it once without holding it, you can simply drop the reference to it, and call:

```
^{
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}();
```

Comment: We can declare and call block at same time. See my comment in Question.

Comment: Yes but I think @Allen tries to save a reference to the block, to be able to call it later, but still be able to invoke it immediately when declaring, I will edit my answer to make it clearer

Comment: No. He know how to call it later. But he want to call it right in place. Like he say in JavaScript example.

Comment: @CRDave Could you show example code for declaring and calling block at same time? Thanks.

Comment: Allen what I gave in my answer (also what @CRDave gave in his comment to your question) will declare and call a block at the same time. Again - assuming you don't need to keep a reference to that block to call it later.